# Conditionally change date format of owl-date-time picker in angular

Tags: angular7

I using owlDateTime(https://daniel-projects.firebaseapp.com/owlng/date-time-picker) picker in may project.
After date selected it shows the mm/dd/yyyy format but I want to change this format to dd/mm/yyyy conditionally.

bellow are my code 
.component.html

```
<input [max]="max" [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dt_date_time" [owlDateTime]="dt_date_time" formControlName="date_time" id="date_time" type="text" class="form-control date-picker date-field hasDatepicker" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" name="date_time" value="">
<owl-date-time  [pickerType]="'calendar'" #dt_date_time></owl-date-time>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solve above problem using following code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DateTimeAdapter } from 'ng-pick-datetime';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-home-layout',
  templateUrl: './home-layout.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home-layout.component.css']
})
export class HomeLayoutComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(dateTimeAdapter: DateTimeAdapter<any>) { 

    let UserAttributes=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('UserAttributes'));
    let country= UserAttributes['custom:country'];
    if(country=='USA'){
       dateTimeAdapter.setLocale('us');
    }else{
       dateTimeAdapter.setLocale('en-IN');
    }

  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

}
```

Comment: It accept the format when I click and select the date. if I type It accepts any format. Eg: I have selected `dateTimeAdapter.setLocale('en-IN')` which is `DD/MM/YYYY` but It accepts when I type `09/28/2019`